# Dynamic image swap with select statements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to set up a simple interaction for users.  The user would be required to select a width then height from separate drop down menus.  I used this as an example to work from: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/working-examples/SCR19/dynselect.html

Once they have made their selections I want an image on the same page to update based on the different combinations of width and height.  The function just needs to be flexible enough to handle the different options the user may select.

If anyone could help me by providing a link to an example or giving me a rough structure to kick start from, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this out and see if its similar to what you had in mind, if so we can tweak it?

http://jsbin.com/anuseb/edit#javascript,html

Comment: This is great.  I now have to combine the functionality of the example I posted with your example.  The user will always have to select a width before getting the height options.  Each width would have a different array of heights associated with it.  Once they select the width then the height options would be displayed and once they select a height the image should update accordingly.  I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to do this.

Comment: Wade,  take a look: http://jsbin.com/anuseb/3/edit#preview and let me know if that's closer to what you have in mind.  the code needs a good bit of cleaning up, this is just testing some stuff out.  I'm sure there's a better more efficient way to do this, but I just started with Javascript and jQuery last week and am trying to answer questions here as it's better than the standard "foo" and "bar" exercises I've found!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I apologize for not explaining what I am trying to do properly.  When the user selects different widths/heights a different image all together would appear.  This is for images of cabinet installations.  For example if they pick 15w/36h they will see one picture and if they pick 15w/23h they will see a totally new picture.  I'm not sure if its best to have all the pictures load up at once or not.  I don't think it would make a huge differences since each picture isn't very big.

Comment: ok.  so you don't need to resize the images  you need a different image to show up based on the two things they select?  I'll play around with it tonight and see what i can come with.  that mayeven be easier.

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Sorry for not making that clear in my initial description.

Comment: ok.  so what youre saying is:
1.  Present user with all width choices
2.  Based on this selection present a range of heights (or present all heights?)
3.  Based on 1 and 2 present an image representing these two choices. 

Does that sound right?

Comment: Yep, you got it perfect.  Just want to present the user with a range of heights, not all of them.  Each width option has slightly different heights available for it.